# How to ask for a recommendation

Tags: english-to-german

Would anybody be able to help me translate this sentence to German?
'Can you recommend a cafe where we could have coffee and cake?'

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd expect coffee and cake to be offered in *every* cafe, so the second part of your question is kind of redundant.

Therefore I'd just say:

> Können Sie mir ein [gutes] Café empfehlen?

If you insist on the whole sentence, you could perhaps say:

> Können Sie mir ein Café empfehlen, in dem ich Kaffee und Kuchen bekommen kann?

Comment: In den USA ist ein Cafe oft etwas, was in Deutschland ein Restaurant wäre, daher ist der Zusatz wegen Kaffee und Kuchen für Amerikaner sinnvoll.

Comment: @Robert ...welchen aber man im *Deutschen* doch weglassen könnte. (Am besten will man ja dies im deutschsprachigen Raum fragen, und nicht in den USA.)

Comment: @tofro Richtig, das war nur als Ergänzung / Erklärung, weil Jürgen darüber gestolpert ist.